# How to adjust the xticks values in a bar plot?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have some `x_data` and `y_data` that go on to the x and y-axis respectively, and my `x_data` has irregular spacings between data points, i.e. [1,2,5,100,250,600,1000,...].

Currently, I'm creating a bar plot using:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
x = range(len(x_data))
bar1 = ax.bar(x, y_data, 0.8, color='g', align='center')
ax.set_xticks(x)
_ = ax.set_xticklabels(x_data)
```

and I want to set my `x_ticks` to be something like [0,100,200,300,...] rather than the actual `x_data`, so between the first and second tick are all the `x_data` data points that fall between the (0,100) range, and between the second and third tick are all the data points that fall between the (100,200) range, and so on.

I tried using `ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(ticker.MultipleLocator(100))` to generate the `x_ticks` that I want, but it looks like the `x-tick` values are the actual `x_data` value at every 100 other ticks rather than the range I mentioned above.

Is it possible to do something that I want?

My current output looks like:
[image]

Comment: @medium-dimensional I have updated my question with a picture. So instead of having the x-values as [1000,9000,17000,...], I want to have something more like [10000,20000,30000,.....].

Comment: What if you don't use `ax.set_xticks(x)` and `_ = ax.set_xticklabels(x_data)`, and see what output the code generates using default xticks?

Comment: The default xticks are the number of bars. For example, if there are 1000 bars in my plot, the x_tick is [0,200,400,600,800,1000].

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, you can define x-ticks' positions as well its labels, and pass it to [`matplotlib.axes.Axes.bar`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_xticks.html).

Here is an example to it:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import numpy as np 

# Generate data
x = np.array([0,2,5,100,250,600])
height = np.random.randint(1, 10, len(x)) * 10 

# Plot a figure
fig, ax = plt.subplots(2)
ax[0].bar(x, height) 
ax[1].bar(x, height)

# Choose the interval to space out xticks
_min = np.min(x)
diff = 50

# Decide positions of ticks
ticks = np.arange(_min, np.max(x) + diff, diff)

# Also, choose labels of the ticks
ax[0].set_xticks(ticks=ticks, labels=ticks)

plt.show()
```

This gives:

[image]

The lower subplot has default x-ticks labels and positions, whereas the upper one's x-ticks has been modified.

Comment: Thanks, but in this case, there is a huge spacing between the bars. Is there a way that I can plot the bars right next to each other and still use the [0,100,200,300,...] x-ticks?

Comment: @sensationti I think you can! The only issue is if there are too many x-ticks, say 0, 100, 200, 300, ... for the data containing bars that is of some order higher than the difference in ticks, i.e., x = [0, 1, 5, 100, 200, 2000, 3000, 50000, ...], the labels might overlap each other and you might not get pretty figure.

Comment: Please try the current solution and share what didn't work.